# Put text on transfer.sh/file.io from ruby

Tags: ruby, httparty

I'm trying to upload text (not a file) to transfer.sh (edit: and file.io/0x0.st) from ruby. All services only give `curl` examples but not anything for programming languages. I tried

```
puts HTTParty.post(
          'https://transfer.sh/',
          multipart: true,
          body: { file: 'some text' }
        ).body.inspect
```

but that just gives me an empty string as result, not the url where I should find the upload.

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T `--upload-file` is a PUT request not a POST request. Also this needs to be a multipart form https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/examples/multipart.rb finally [`curb`](https://github.com/taf2/curb#http-post-file-upload) is a `curl` library for ruby so that might be easier for you to translate

Comment: transfer.sh also lists `curl -i -F filedata=@/tmp/hello.txt -F filedata=@/tmp/hello2.txt https://transfer.sh/` as a sample, so both should work, and my sample does use multipart; I'm also looking at services like file.io and 0x0.st, which don't do PUT.

Comment: PUT is also a lot slower from the few tests I did (10-20 seconds for a 6k text file)